# Unicode string display on Django template

Tags: python, django, json, unicode

I am using django v1.5.*, I am going to render the a variable named "foobar" which is a json obj and including unicode string.

```
def home( request ):
    import json
    foo = {"name": u"赞我们一下"}
    bar = json.dumps( foo )
    return render_to_response( 'myapp/home.html',
        { "foobar": bar, },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

And in my template, I encode the json obj in javascript and then append to the div, it can display the expected string:

```
  foobar=JSON.encode('{{foobar|safe}}'); 
  $("#foobar").html(foobar.name);`
```

then I can get the `赞一下我们` on my web page.
But I found that if I use the variable directly:

`<div id="foobar">{{ foobar }}</div>`

it will display the unicode string as byte string:
`{ "name":"\u8d5e\u4e00\u4e0b\u6211\u4eec" }`
Even if I using the `{{foobar|safe}}` then nothing change.

Now, I want to ask why this happend or is anything wrong of me? What should I do if I do want to using the variable directly as `{{ foobar }}` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar = json.dumps(foo, ensure_ascii=False)` will result in `bar` being a `unicode` object; without [ensure_ascii=False](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), `bar` is a `str`.

Django's [smart_text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/unicode/#general-string-handling) method might also be useful for conversions.

Comment: Thx! That what I need. & Your reference URLs also give me good explanation as well!! All can find in the official website, it's no doubt that I should read the document more carefully than before.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="foobar">{{ foobar }}</div>
```

> will display the unicode string as byte string: `{ "name":"\u8d5e\u4e00\u4e0b\u6211\u4eec" }`

This is displaying the whole object in its JSON-encoded form. Whilst you could use `json.dumps(..., ensure_ascii=False)` to keep non-ASCII characters like the Chinese in their raw form rather than encoded into ASCII-safe-JSON, this would still give you `{"name": "赞一下我们"}` which is probably not what you want.

If you only want the `name` property of the object included in the div, you will need to pass the item `foo['name']` to your template - or the whole of `foo` and have the template include `{{foo.name}}` - rather than including the whole encoded JSON object from `foobar`.

```
foobar=JSON.encode('{{foobar|safe}}');
```

There is no method `encode` on the ECMA standard `JSON` object, so I don't know what that's doing.

The JSON-encoding method is `JSON.stringify`. But you don't want to encode here - you already have a string with a JSON representation of an object here because you encoded it above at the server side in the call to `json.dumps`. Probably you meant:

```
var foobar = JSON.parse('{{foobar|safe}}');
```

which would work for your particular value of `name`, but not necessarily in general. For example if the name was `a\nb` then you would get:

```
JSON.parse('{"name": "a\nb"}')
```

in which case the `\n` would get parsed by the JavaScript interpreter as being a newline character in the string, and so the string parsed as JSON would be:

```
{"name": "a
b"}
```

which is a syntax error. There are also security issues here - contrary to the `|safe` assertion, this is not safe. If the `name` property contained the string `</script` then you would end up with a prematurely-ended script element, which can lead to cross-site scripting attacks:

```
<script>
var foobar = JSON.parse('</script>
<script>alert();//attacker code here');</script>
```

You could attempt to get around these by doing a second layer of JS string literal encoding on the JSON at the server side, and manually replace `<` with `\u003C`. But probably it's best to take a different approach - generating executable code on the fly is fraught with problems in general, especially when you have multiple different syntaxes in the mix (Python/Django-template, HTML and JS/JSON).

If you write data to the document (for example in a `data-` attribute) rather than the script then you can keep the normal and safe template behaviour of HTML-escaping. Then the JS side can read the data out of the DOM. For example:

```
<div id="foobar" data-foobar="{{ foobar }}">
...

var foobar = $('#foobar').data('foobar');
```

(jQuery's `data` method implicitly does the `JSON.parse` for you.)

This helps with separation of concerns, getting JS out into external scripts, and potentially eventually using Content-Security-Policy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the element within the dict, without JSON-encoding it.

```
return render_to_response(..., {..., 'foo': foo}, ...)
```

...

```
{{ foo.name }}
```