# Char is UTF But I Still See Encrypted Letters

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

When some Korean texts went through the Django server, I printed the 'data' variable just to see if this encryption issue was caused by Python. Fortunately, Korean letters show well:

[image: Python console]

However, when the letters go through the Django templates, it shows like this:

[image: Encrypted Korean Letters]

Notice the words like

```
\uc57c,\ud734,\ud734,\uc57c,\uc57c
\ud734,\uc57c,\uc57c,\ud734,\ud734
```

Below is the source code of the templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Group Share</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>{{ user.first_name }} opened {{ room_name }} group schedule</p>
    <h3>Group Members</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for member in group_members %}
            <li>{{ member.first_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <div id="group-schedule" class="flex">

    </div>

    <textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br>

    {{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}

    <script charset="UTF-8">
        const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'ws://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/groupshare/channel/'
            + roomName
        );

        chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
            const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.message + '\n');
            document.querySelector('#chat-log').value = (data.new_schedule + '\n');
            console.log(data.new_schedule)
        };
...
...
...
```

Settings are all set for UTF-8. Everyone tells that UTF-8 setting will solve the problem but it hasn't worked out yet.

Comment: This might give some insights? I have no direct experience with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833772/unicode-string-display-on-django-template

Comment: Wow, this has worked! Thank you so much!